# Importing incomplete data to matrix in R

Tags: r, math, matrix, statistics

I'm currently trying to manipulate a matrix full of zeros that I want to fill with numbers.
The purpose of the matrix is to describe a distribution of density.

The thing is, in order to do so, I only have three vectors describing non-zero values that are in the matrix.
That is, the first contains the ordinate value of the cell that contains a number, the second contains the abscissa value and the third contains the density value.

For instance, if I have a density of 3 in the [3,2] cell, I'd have three vectors as so:

vector1 = (3), vector2 = (2), vector3 = (3)

I have unsuccessfully tried to fill it with a for loop, and since I'm not very skilled with R I'm having a hard time figuring out how to fill that matrix.

Thanks in advance for your answers, should you have any question please don't hesitate.

Comment: `m[ cbind( vector1 , vector2 ) ] <- vector3` where `m` is the matrix object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using R built-in vectorised methods, this is a beautiful breeze. You are looking for the `[<-` replacement function. Here is an example:

```
m <- matrix( 0 , 4 , 4 )
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0


v1 <- c( 3 , 2 , 1 )
v2 <-  c( 2 , 1 , 4 )
v3 <- c( 10, 20 , 30 )

m[ cbind( v1 , v2 ) ] <- v3
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0   30
#[2,]   20    0    0    0
#[3,]    0   10    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    0
```